# Use of “become in debt”

Tags: grammaticality

I couldn’t understand why we use amount of debt before “in debt “ . I mean would it be wrong to use it like :

> I become in a $10000 debt .

Answer (score 2):

That is not a grammatical sentence.

> I became $10000 in debt

is maybe what you meant. You can specify the amount to indicate how deeply in debt you were (or became). $100 in debt is different from $1000 in debt, which is different from $10000 in debt.

Answer (score 2):

It's the usual phrasing for a measure of a state, given before the state itself.

> I am £28,000 in debt.
>   We are 40,000 feet in the air.
>   Join us 20,000 leagues under the sea.